Jest проверка валидации
Необходимо проверить тестом:

Валидация номера карты пропускает корректный номер карты.

// Функция проверяющая валидацию номера карты
export function numberValid(element) {
  return valid.number(element);
}

Тест должен быть прописан в таком виде? Или как то можно сравнить со значением *isValid: true*?
test('Валидация номера карты пропускает корректный номер карты.', () => {
  expect(numberValid('2201382000000021')).toEqual({
    card: {
      code: {
        name: 'CVP2',
        size: 3
      },
      gaps: [4, 8, 12],
      lengths: [16, 17, 18, 19],
      matchStrength: 4,
      niceType: 'Mir',
      patterns: [
        [2200, 2204]
      ],
      type: 'mir',
    },
    isPotentiallyValid: true,
    isValid: true,
  });
});

